# How do I remove the css generated by autoptimize?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, google-pagespeed, autoptimize

[image: please view image]

Compressed with Autoptimize. The plugin itself produces files as you can see in the picture and causes problems. Is there any way to remove them?

Comment: I am not sure, but this might help you https://aoxoa.co/inline-defer-render-blocking-css-autoptimize/

Answer (score 0):

Autoptimize helps with the loading speed of the website. It concatenates scripts and styles and compresses them to serve them in as few files/requests as possible, and that's usually good for performance analysis.

However, if for any reason is causing you problems and you have to remove it, you just need to go to the admin side, plugins and deactivate Autoptimize and it won't show anymore.

You could also just go to the plugin's settings and specify which options you want active or not `Settings -> Autoptimize`